# Issue in retrieving the custom node properties as well as deleteing the node in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have using alfresco 5.0.d version for the past 3 weeks.I have created the node as agency and type as agencyType as well as created the properties such as name,code and createdDate and able to save the data in node properties.In search option,will take the name as input and need to retrieve the code and createdDate based on name.

Webscript API for accessing the node properties below

```
nodes= search.luceneSearch("TEXT:"+filter, "@agency:name", true);
```

Result:

> "Node Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content,
>   Node Aspects:
>   [{http://www.alfresco.org/model/rendition/1.0}renditioned,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}titled,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}ownable,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}auditable,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}referenceable,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}localized,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}author,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/forum/1.0}discussable]", "Node
>   Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content, Node
>   Aspects:
>   [{http://www.alfresco.org/model/rendition/1.0}renditioned,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}titled,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}ownable,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}auditable,
>   {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}referenceable

But I need to get the node properties based on name property which I am passing as need to know for deleting the node based on name property.

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node.properties` Provides access to all the properties of this node. The properties returned are accessed via an associative array. Properties of a node can be accessed in the following ways:

```
Example: node.properties["name"]

Example: node.properties.name
```

[Source](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-ScriptNode.html)

This help you?